# Resharper 6 create auto property by default

Tags: c#, resharper

When I write code and need new property, i simply write propery name as it would exist already and choose action from menu:
[image: create new property in resharper]

Problem is, that it generates code like this:

```
 protected int SomeNewProperty
    {
        get { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
    }
```

So I need to go there and manually adjust that (actually I prefer to choose Create field from menu and change it to auto property). Anyway, I thought, may be there is a way to change default behavior of "Create property", that it would create auto property instantly?

**Update**

In Resharper 8 auto properties are available and may be set by default!

[image: Resharper 8 Option Screen]

Comment: I noticed there is an open feature request for this:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-191556

May be worth voting for!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just when you click *Create property* it will halt on the type. Hit <kbd>tab</kbd> and you will get a context menu with the option to use `Auto property`.

[image]

Comment: close enough, if it is really impossible to save this behavior as default, i'll mark it as answer.

Comment: As seen below it is only possible to change what default member body does. The thing is that you probably don't want to have auto property at all times. Then this context menu is pretty handy.

Comment: Just come across this, never knew it existed! Ta

Answer (score 21):

**You cannot do this in R# (at least in v6)**. That is, create a pseudo property and have resharper generate the Auto Property stub.

**You can still use the superior method that Visual Studio uses**. Type out your new property which will show as a syntax error and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> shows VS mini menu. Then just hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and straight away, the job is done.

It does not take you to the class file which can be distracting too. To use the shortcut above, you don't even need to have you cursor on the broken property name.

So this is better than the method described by Rickard as it is faster and less distracting you away from the code you are writing.

Comment: this is a great suggestion, this should be the answer. resharper should work like this.

Comment: Good stuff. I can't believe R# doesn't do this. This should probably be a part of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is an option to change default body style.

However, the close you can get is

```
    protected int SomeProperty
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }
```

[image: Resharper Options]

Answer (score 1):

There is a default snippet that comes with Visual Studio called 'prop' Just type that, hit , give a type name  and give it a name.  Done and done.

I know that doesn't answer your question in terms of Resharper, but it is functionality already provided by the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: well, problem is, that i need to go to the place property to be created first, and i hate do that.

Comment: yeah, working sucks.  I usually hire a programmer to do this kind of stuff =)

Comment: @MikeCole The snippet approach IS more efficient.  Thanks for pointing that out.